# Selecting non sequential columns including dynamic row number

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a macro that selects two non-sequential columns that have a dynamic row reference.

I.e. The static macro would be like this:

```
Range("A7:A54,C7:C54").Select
```

My issue is that the last row is dynamic, so I have added a variable called Height that calculates this (not important how I get this row number, so will not show that code here).

The macro I have tried to implement is therefore:

```
Range("A7:A" & Height, "C7:C" & Height).Select
```

Height being 54 in this case.

But when I run the macro it select the column in between as well! I.e. also column B (A7:C54)

Can anyone help me figure out how I can adjust the code to not select the column in between?

Comment: `Range("A7:A" & Height & ",C7:C" & Height).Select`

Comment: Though one should normally [avoid Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either as BigBen commented

```
Range("A7:A" & Height & ",C7:C" & Height).Select
```

but address strings are limited to 255 characters, so if you run into that limit you would need to use `union()` with multiple range objects:

```
Union(Range("A7:A" & Height), Range("C7:C" & Height)).Select
```